Jetpack Compose: how to set initial a11y focus
I cannot figure out how to set the initial focus for Talkback for Compose elements...  I am able to do it for keyboard focus just fine...
Here is an example where you click on the first thing with a keyboard and the second thing takes focus.  This works:
@Composable
fun TestAutoFocus() {
    val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column {
        Text("First",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    requester.requestFocus()
                })
        Text(
            "Second",
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(requester)
                .clickable {  }
        )
    }
}


Similarly, if you add LaunchedEffect to request focus initially, this also works for keyboard focus:
@Composable
fun TestAutoFocus() {
    val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column {
        Text("First",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                })
        Text(
            "Second",
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(requester)
                .clickable {  }
        )
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        requester.requestFocus()
    }
}


Switching to Talkback, I can hook up the first thing so when you click on it with Talkback, a11y-focus is put onto the second thing:
@Composable
fun TestAutoFocus() {
    val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column {
        Text("First",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    requester.requestFocus()
                })
        Text(
            "Second",
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(requester)
                .focusable()
        )
    }
}

However, I cannot figure out how to make the second thing focused by Talkback "on load"... Trying LaunchedEffect doesn't work:
@Composable
fun TestAutoFocus() {
    val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column {
        Text("First",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                })
        Text(
            "Second",
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(requester)
                .focusable()
        )
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        requester.requestFocus()
    }
}

What am I missing here?  Please help...
